# How can I fix 'no wubildr' error in WUBI on Windows 7?

Tags: wubi, 64-bit, windows-7

Good Evening All,

I just got my HP Laptop Back from the factory and then I tried to install Ubuntu.

It got through the whole installation, however, when I restarted and chose Ubuntu a quick screen flashes that says:

> Try (hd0,0) NTFS5: no wubildr
>   Try (hd0,1) NTFS5:

Then it quickly goes to the Boot Loader which I am presented with:

> Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
>   Windows Vista (loader) (on /dev/sda2)
>   Windows Vista (loader) (on /dev/sda3)

Of course if I click Win 7 it'll go to the main screen to choose between Win 7 or Ubuntu, if I choose Vista, it'll come with an error of sorts.

The strange thing is, I looked in my C:/ Drive and I see wubildr and wubilder.mbr

Idk if it makes a difference but I am running a 64-bit processor. Installed the 64-bit desktop version and am presented with ultra-fail.

I've gone to: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?s=4d54a8d3760f6fe805156524b7ab9acf&t=798283&page=1

But have had no luck.

Comment: It is happening to my laptop too.
What seems to fix the issue is that i press PAUSE immediately after i select ubuntu, wait for a couple of minutes and then unpause and i can see the kernel editions again.
That seems to work almost each time.
Hope it helps
PS: i have a 64bit windows 7 and ubuntu 10.04

Comment: anonymous this worked for me. Simple solution

Comment: just got the same error but i have had ubuntu 10.10 installed for 2 weeks now just got it set up the way i want it so i reboot my pc and i get the error please help im a total N00b

Comment: Many people are experiencing this or similar problems; we should reopen this, it's not too localized.

Comment: @EliahKagan The "No Wubildr" error is just a Grub4dos diagnostic as it looks for the `/wubildr` file on all partitions. It reports this message for each partition that doesn't have it. When it finds it, it uses it. Wubi users report this often because it's something they can see, but it rarely is helpful in and of itself. E.g. in this case, the error is that the package `lupin-support` is not present, so Grub doesn't create entries for the actual Wubi install. But in other cases, it could be a `root.disk` corruption, or maybe a graphics card issue requiring `nomodeset` (if you get my drift)

Comment: Also, this is from 2010 ; I don't know how helpful re-opening it now will be.

Comment: @bcbc What you've just said seems most of the way toward an answer. :)

Comment: @EliahKagan yeah I haven't seen this particular question before... or else I might have answered it, but this usually happens when installing uncommon flavours with Wubi e.g. Mythbuntu (back in 2010). Someone would add support for the flavour in Wubi, but forget to include the lupin package on the ISO so Wubi would install, but Grub would be unable to 'find it'. And since nobody tests Wubi much, it would go unnoticed except by some confused new users.

Answer (score 2):

I never found a real fix for it when I ran Wubi on my laptop. For me, it came down to finding the version of Wubi/Ubuntu that worked. For example, 10.04 (64-bit) refused to install properly, but 9.10 worked like a trooper (until kernel panicked a few days later, but that's a different story).

"No wubildr" turned out to not be a problem in 9.10 -- I just had to wait a couple minutes and then the loading finished fine.

Strangely, I have no issues running Wubi on my new desktop -- the "no wubildr" error doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Yup, `no wubildr` flashes by quickly on my system as the bootloader is scanning partitions for wubildr. Waiting is a good way t solve this. Not sure why it takes so long on @AnnaLear and the OP's systems.

Answer (score 1):

It is posible that wubi is looking on the hidden 100MB NTFS partision, that windows 7 some times makes, instead of your C drive.
That you are getting two bootloader steps one with Vista options sounds like you have installed grub in the normal fashion.
I strongly advice you to use the CD installation for Ubuntu, on this setup, instead of Wubi.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure your ntfs is clean.  Can you boot into your livecd and run a `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdaX` where sdaX is your drive/partition (if this isn't installed, you can install the `ntfsprogs` package.  If you don't know what your drive was assigned, you can run `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: Or possibly run a disk check in Windows instead of playing with partitions in LiveCD? @Austin Just boot your Windows system, go to `Computer`, right click your hard disk partition that you installed  Wubi to, click properties, tools, and choose the option to check the disk for errors.