# Wubi doens't work anymore - shows 'No wubildr' error

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, wubi

**Basics:**

HP Mini 311
Ubuntu netbook edition 10.04 (installed via Wubi)

**Symptoms:**

I load to Windows Boot Manager as usual. Options are Windows 7 and Ubuntu Netbook, like usual. Selecting Windows 7 does as it should. Loading Ubuntu Netbook, though, does not take me to the usual screen where it lets me select versions of Ubuntu (sorry for bad wording, not sure what the real name is called; it's where you select from about 6 items; I always picked the first due to lack of knowledge without issue). Instead it flashes an error in white on a black screen then restarts very quickly.

**It took me a few restarts, but here is the error:**

```
Try (hd0,0): NTSF5 No wubildr
Try (hd0,1): NTSF5:
```

**Situation:**

I have no clue what caused it. The only thing I did last night on Ubuntu was install Skype, but the mic didn't work instantly so I got lazy and switched to Windows 7 and used Skype on there. When I tried to switch back to Ubuntu it began this. (There may be something I forget... it was 5 in the morning). There were no recent updates that I remember. No weird activity. Just... random.

Help please?

Comment: What do you mean by boot manager??

Comment: Possible Duplicate [How can I fix 'no wubildr' error in WUBI on Windows 7?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2677/how-can-i-fix-no-wubildr-error-in-wubi-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

If Windows can boot normally, then see below

- The solution is in the **[Wubi Megathread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1639198)**,
  problem #2 solution #2
- If, for some reason, that does not work, try problem #2, solution #1
- In the worst case scenario, if solution #1 does not work.You can recover your data from the Wubi install from within Windows.
- You can use **[ext2read](http://ext2read.blogspot.com/)** to recover any important data from the Ubuntu root.disk.
- Then, uninstall Wubi using Add/Remove Programs.Download and do a fresh install of Wubi.
- Once it starts for the first time and everything is good, do this,Go to System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager and select the grub-pc and grub-common packages. Click on Package > Lock Version.
- That should stop the problem happening again.