# Computadora no arranca (Computer Doesn't Start Up)

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, dual-boot, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wubi doens't work anymore - shows 'No wubildr' error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18928/wubi-doenst-work-anymore-shows-no-wubildr-error)

Two weeks ago I made an update and when it finished,it asked for a reboot. never again booted, when I turn on the pc, the grub appears, offering me, Start Windows or Ubuntu. When I start ubuntu this appeared:

```
Try(hd0,0):NTFS5: No wubilder
Try(hd0,1):NTFS5:
```

Somebody can help me, with that?

Comment: deberias de usar el traductor de google, ya que este sitio es principalmente en ingles, ahora has instalado Ubuntu usando wubi?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18928/wubi-doenst-work-anymore-shows-no-wubildr-error

Comment: At this time please only post questions and answers in English.