# "No wubildr" Problem

Tags: installation, 12.10, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix ‘no wubildr’ error in WUBI on Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2677/how-can-i-fix-no-wubildr-error-in-wubi-on-windows-7)

Today, I installed Ubuntu v.12.10 under Windows 7 using Wubi.exe. Everything went fine and the program asked me to restart the computer. It then went on installing Ubuntu, showing some text including some warnings, which I assume, are normal. It then shows the screen where you can choose between starting Windows 7 or Ubuntu. I press down and enter to choose Ubuntu, and all that happens is a short message that flashes and says:

Try (hd0,0) NTFS5: no wubildr

Try (hd0,1) NTFS5:

(For about half a second only)

Of course I already did a google research but all I found were people where the problem occured under older versions of Ubuntu or where Ubuntu still loaded after a little while.

But in my case, a dark red screen appears during approximately 2-3 seconds and then my notebook (a Samsung R510) restarts showing the selection screen between Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Maybe I could add that it is an older notebook with an Intel Core 2 Duo CPU and an Nvidia Geforce Graphics Card.

I have no other partitions than the normal "C:" drive where my windows is installed. I have no USB devide plugged in and no other OS installed or anything...

I already tried installing and uninstalling Wubi 3 times, but it doesn't change anything. I also checked and the wubildr files are all there. One in the C: drive and one in the ubuntu folder, as it is supposed to be.

I just wanted to try out Ubuntu as an alternative OS before maybe changing completely...

Please help me, I really cannot find any solution to this problem.